# XML : save data from sql server to file

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to save data from a SQL Server database table to a file, then load it into another database that has the same table already created in it

How can I do this? I know there should be some simple way of doing it, but stackoverflowsearch and google aren't yielding good answers (or I'm not asking a good question).

Comment: I would:

bcp export to xml (or maybe csv). bcp import to new database/table.

see 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

It's located under the SQL Server startup menu folder.

[image: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard]

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no simple way to do this in SQL only.

Probably best way to handle this is to create your own simple application in whatever programming language that will query first database, write the file where it needs to be written and also import data into another database.